# Improve performance of database access

Tags: java, performance, asynchronous, database-performance, spring-integration

I have an application that listens on a port for UDP datagrams. I use a UDP inbound channel adapter to listen on this port. My UDP channel adapter is configured to use a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to dispatch incoming UDP datagrams. After the UDP channel adapter I use a direct channel. My channel has only one subscriber i.e. a service activator.

The service adds the incoming messages to a synchronized list stored in memory. Then, I have a single thread that retrieves the content of the list every 5 seconds and does a batch update to a MySQL database.

My problem:

1. A first bulk of message arrives. The threads of my ThreadPoolExecutor get the incoming message from the UDP channel adapter and add them to the synchronized list. Let's say 10000 messages have been received and inserted.
2. The background thread retrieves the 10000 messages and does a batch update (JdbcTemplate.update(String[]).
3. At this point, the background thread waits the response from the database. But, now, because it takes time to the database to execute the 10000 INSERT, 20000 messages have been received and are present in the list.
4. The background thread receives a response from the database. Then, it retrieves the 20000 messages and does a batch update (JdbcTemplate.update(String[]).
5. It takes more time to the database to execute the INSERT and during this time, 35000 messages have been received and stored in the list.

The heap size grows constantly and causes after a certain time a memory execption.

I'm trying to find solution to improve the performance of my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing 10,000 records every 5 seconds is quite alot for any database to sustain.

You need to consider other options

- use a different data store e.g a NoSQL data store, or a flat file.
- ensure you have good write performance on your disks e.g using a write cache.
- use a disk sub-system with mutliple disks or an SSD drive.

Comment: Ask a DBA to tune/reconfigure database, or use a hashed random file (eventually with dual path) on a SAN (or on multi disks configuration)

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions

a. Do you really need a single synchronized list? Can't you have a group of lists, and let's say divide the work between these lists , let's say by running hashCode on a key of the data?

b. Can you use a thread pool of threads that read information from the list (I would use a queue here, by the way) , this way, when one thread is "stuck" due to heavy batch insertion, other threads can still read "jobs" from the queue and perform them?

c. Is your database co-hosted on the same machine as the application? This can improve performance

d. Can you post your insert query? maybe someone can offer you a way to optimize it?

Answer (score 2):

Use a Database Connection pool so that you don't have to wait on the commit on any one thread.  Just grab the next available connection and do parallel inserts.

Comment: I understand your solution but I'm afraid that the load on the database will be too high (as Peter said it).

Comment: Well that's an architectural issue then.  Spread your database across more disks to allow for more parallel writing to disk through more controller channels.  -- Sorry Peter, didn't see your answer above, all good advice

Comment: One last bit of advice, databases will often surprise you.  While it is a reasonable assumption, you don't really know until you try.  Performance is about continually solving the next bottleneck.  Your question asks how to avoid the latency of the commit, parallel writes is the answer.  The database being configured to handle it is a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

I get 5.000 inserts per second sustained on a SQLServer table, but that required quite a few optimizations. Did not use all of the tips below, some might be of use to you.

- Check the MySQL Insert Speed documentation tips in
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html
- Parallelize the insert process
- Aggregate messages if possible. Instead of storing all messages insert a row with information about received messages in a timeframe, of a certain type etc.
- Change the table to have no Indexes or Foreign keys except for the primary key
- Switch to writing to a textfile (and import that during the night in a loaddata bulk file insert if you really want it in the database)
- Use a seperate database instance to serve only your table
- ...